# posting code in this forum

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

I'm new to this forum but I've used and still do use dozens of forums.  But on this forum I have been unable to successfully past code and have it accepted.  I get the following error....

•Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

I try everything but I can never get the code accepted.  It is perfectly formatted just as it is in the program.  what's the key?  Thanks,
Gary

Comment: Paste your code and select your whole code & above the text box you will find `{}` brackets if you press that then it will be formatted as code.

Comment: Pedant: This isn't a "forum".

Answer (score 3):

Paste your code, then highlight your code, then hit the "{}" button. It should do the trick